# Determine a function f(n) that describes number of times a statement is executed

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I determine a function f(n) describing number of times the statement x = x + 2 is executed in terms of n in the following algorithm?

```
input j
x = 0,
for i: j to j^2 do
    x: = x + 1
```

**Note:** I'm not looking for run time.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question.

From what I understand so far:
j^2-j total iterations, meaning times x+1 is called
So half that?
(j^2-j)/2

Could you clarify?

Comment: @brianxautumn I need a function f(n) that describes or indicates the number of times the statement x: = x + 1 is executed. Mind you this is not in any particular language. The answer has to be a function

Comment: was the x = x + 2 a typo in the question?

Comment: No. It is pseudocode. It's the same as x = x + 2.

Comment: you said  x: = x + 1 in the statement above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f(n) = n^2-n
```

essentially just directly calculating x

Comment: Why the return though? Shouldn't it be f(n) = n^2-n? Also, why the final -n ?

Comment: Return to get the value that you calculated. the -n because you start counting from n. For example 3 would be from 3 to 9. Thats 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9. Or 9 - 3 iterations.

Comment: I see, you're right! But with the return it wouldn't be a function wouldn't it?

Comment: I know, my point though is that the function I require is a mathematical function. There is no languages involved here.

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted a pseudocode function! Check update.

Comment: No, you're right, I did not specify, then again this is posted in discrete math. Thanks again!